# Function for saving data does not work in php

Tags: php, function, save

I trying to separate the code php and the code html in 2 files.

So I'm doing many functions that will be executed in different part of my page.

For the moment I'm trying to make a function for saving a small form data.

So I have written that code:

```
function addAnnonce($session) {
    $sql = "SELECT `nom`,`prenom`,`type` FROM `gestionnaire` WHERE `id`={$session}";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $donnees = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

function saveAnnonce($form, $annonce, $to) {
    if (isset($form)) {
        addAnonce($_SESSION['login']);
        $by = $donnees['nom'] . '&nbsp;' . $donnees['prenom'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `cometchat_announcements` SET
    `announcement`  ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($annonce) . "',
    `by`            ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($by) . "',
    `time`          ='" . mysql_real_escape_string(time()) . "',
    `to`            ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($to) . "'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        echo "<div class=\"success\">L'annoncea bien &eacute;t&eacute; ajout&eacute;e , vous pouvez continuer vos actions<br>La mise &agrave; jour interviendra apr&egrave;s actualisation</div>";
        echo "<SCRIPT type=\"text/javascript\"> 
<!-- 
alert(\"Ajout d\'une nouvelle annonce : Ok !\");
// --> 
</SCRIPT> ";
    }
}
    isset($_POST['enreg']) ? saveAnnonce($_POST['enreg'], $_POST['annonce'],$_POST['to']) :'' ;
```

The trouble is that it display to me a blank page.

I really do not understand why.

It should display the form but I think something is wrong but I can not see what.

I've tried it with xdebug but it does not show to me nothing.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: offtopic: use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: why do you use the `?:` operator instead of a proper `if` for the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning `$donnees` to the workflow, so `$donnees` in `saveAnnonce()` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I added return $donnees in the first function but I still have the same trouble

Comment: Your code should look like
`function addAnnonce($session) {
    $sql = "SELECT nom,prenom,type FROM gestionnaire WHERE id={$session}";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

function saveAnnonce($form, $annonce, $to) {
    if (isset($form)) {
        $donnees = addAnonce($_SESSION['login']);
        $by = $donnees['nom'] . '&nbsp;' . $donnees['prenom'];`

Answer (score 1):

You are also misspelling `addAnnonce` when calling it (`addAnonce`).

Note that you do not need the `if(isset($form))`, it will always be set since it's a required argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I've corrected the misspel but Still have the same trouble

Comment: As @banzsh mentioned, you also need to actually save the return from the addAnnonce as well. $donnees = addAnnonce($_SESSION['login']);